# Does Family Safety Work On Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, family-safety

On PC's you can filter web browsing, block apps and more via the [Microsoft Family Safety site](http://account.microsoft.com/family). If Windows 10 is truly a "united OS", can we do the same for phones?

Comment: It's far to early to tell, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to update here, the [Family Safety site](http://account.microsoft.com/family) has been updated to allow app blocking, web filtering, and more on Windows 10 Mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, a Lumia 635 that was previously associated with Family Safety on Windows Phone 8.1, has lost all connections with Windows 10 Preview (FastLane) installation.
So, not yet implemented.

Answer (score 1):

There are no new options in Windows 10 Technical preview for phones related to family safety (yet).